# Impossible to modify calls in progress

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I'm building an IVR with Twilio Studio and Twilio Functions and i'm trying to modify live call in progress.

Actually, I put the client calling my IVR  to a queue with the `<Enqueue>` verb.
In the same time, i initiate a call to an agent, i warn him a customer is online with the `<Say>` verb, and then i use the `<Dial>` verb, for dial the agent to the customer queue.
Everything works good.

But now, i want modify the live call in progress beetwin my agent and the customer.
I tried to follow up the guide :https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-modify-calls-in-progress-node-js
but it doesent works for me..

At this point i have two CallSid :
1) CallSid when the customer called my IVR
2) CallSid when i initiated a call to an agent

I tried modify both calls, nothing happen...

This is my code for modify the live call in progress

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
    let client = context.getTwilioClient();
    console.log(event.ca)


    client.calls(event.ca)
      .update({twiml: '<Response><Say>Ahoy there</Say></Response>'})
      .then((resp) => {
              console.log(resp); // Succès !
                    callback();

       });

};
```

I get the response "resp" from the callback function with some informations mean the update function worked good, but the `<Say>`Ahoy there`</Say>` doesn"t work...

Comment: Are you able to modify the same calls using a URL instead of sending TwiML in the request? When you say it doesn't work, do you mean the call carries on as if nothing happens or that there is an error or it hangs up?

Comment: @philnash No, even with URL it dosen"t work with Twilio Functions BUT with curl (postman) it works ... Yes, call carries on as if nothing happens.

Comment: Can I ask when you call that Twilio Function?

Comment: @philnash  i call it from directly from my browser, with the url of my Twilio Function + the callSID in get parameter.
Something like that : https://topaz-jackal-1081.twil.io/modify?ca=CALLSID

Comment: Can you post the entire Twilio Function that you're using? It must be something to do with the code outside of what you posted.

Comment: To add code, it's best to edit your question.

Comment: @philnash There is the full code => https://jsfiddle.net/4d0qjagk/

Comment: What happens in your browser when you load the URL with the correct call sid?

Comment: @philnash Nothing, white screen. And then, in my console, i can see the output of my console.log inside the success callback.. but nothing happen on the call in progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think I know what's going on. Thanks for answering all the questions.

It's my belief that you are using a version of the Twilio client that is older than the update with direct TwiML feature. So, it is sending an update call, discarding the TwiML, and appearing to be successful even though it does nothing.

Head to your [Functions configuration page](https://www.twilio.com/console/functions/configure) and update the Twilio module to the latest version, `3.36.0`, then try again.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: It worked ! Thank you very much. I tried with empty version, it worked too, i guess he took the latest version automatically.

Comment: I think leaving it empty picks the latest. This could cause unexpected effects in your functions if they automatically update the version when you deploy them. So I would recommend saving the version you are comfortable with.